# eps file upload

Tags: feature-request, images

I wish it were possible to upload/include eps files. The insert-image thing doesn't recognize them as images.

**Question:** Is it mandatory to ask an actual *question* when posting a feature-request "question"?

Comment: I think the theory that a question should contain a question does not apply to meta.

Comment: Sorry to state the obvious, but... 1) you can upload an eps-file to a personal web page and post the link in the usual way, 2) it may be difficult to use eps-files the same way as jpg-, gif-, or png-files simply because most browsers cannot display them. I suspect suitable add-ons may exist, but I'm too ignorant. 3) I produce the eps files I need in my TeX-documents with Mathematica, and it is equally easy to also produce a png-file also. The same holds for other CASs. Presumably you have old eps-files and no convenient way of regenerating it in (or converting it to) another format. IDK :-(

Comment: Anyway, this would be a nice thing to have (+1), but I'm a bit skeptical whether it can be usefully/easily done with tools/tricks at the server end only.

Comment: You see, [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support) does not even mention eps.

Comment: [Some relevant discussion](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=401205)

Comment: Please don't.  You should convert your image to a form that is acceptable, rather than asking all readers to convert it themselves.  And won't EPS files pose a security risk to anyone who opens them?

Comment: There is some merit to what @GEdgar says. At least [Microsoft thinks so](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/support-for-eps-images-has-been-turned-off-in-office-a069d664-4bcf-415e-a1b5-cbb0c334a840). I don't know but just may be they have a real reason?

Comment: @GEdgar I didn't realize there were security problems with eps.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So you'd think, but I've got more than one vehement "What's your question?" on meta...

Comment: Ok, it's never going to happen -- I'm not going to try to talk Mozilla and Google into changing things. Yes, converting to some supported format is not hard, but "converting" vector graphics to bitmapped graphics is simply _evil_. I did that last night, couldn't sleep afterwards...

Comment: An alternative to converting vector to bitmap is to convert to a vector format with better browser support: SVG. This should be possible with the free (gratis and libre) software InkScape. It's not a panacea because SVG isn't a first class citizen in Stack Exchange software either: [related mother meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92568/164922).